# Scrape wikipedia "prop=linkshere" more efficiently?

Tags: web-scraping, wikipedia-api

My scraping code works, but it seems inefficient: I have to send a bazillion "continue" requests to get it all.  Here's the initial request:

```
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=linkshere&format=json&maxlag=2&titles=Korn
```

and I get back a continuation number, so I follow with:

```
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=linkshere&format=json&maxlag=2&titles=Korn&lhcontinue=20653
```

over and over and over until the end. Each request gives a tiny amount of the total data.

Am I missing something simple to get more data on each request?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The default [`lhlimit`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Linkshere) for each response is 10. Change it to `max`, e.g. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=linkshere&format=json&maxlag=2&titles=Korn&lhlimit=max .

Comment: Thank you, perfect!